# EF Core HasOptional WithOptionalDependent

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following tables in my database:

```
Product                                 ResourceAssociation
-------                                 ------------------
Name                          /-------> Id
ResourceAssociation_Id ------/         SomeProperty
```

So Product has a ResourceAssociation_Id, which is a FK to the ResourceAssociation table.

This is a legacy application that had an Entity Framework 6 map that contained this piece of code:

```
HasOptional(t => t.ResourceAssociation).WithOptionalDependent().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

I'm looking to port this to EF Core. EF Core doesn't have the HasOptional anymore, it seems. I've tried this:

```
builder.HasOne(t => t.ResourceAssociation)
    .WithOne().HasForeignKey("ResourceAssociation_Id")
    .IsRequired(false)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

I've also tried replacing the `WithOne` with `WithMany`. But it doesn't work.

When I try to create a new Product, without a ResourceAssociation (because it isn't required), EF Core still tells me my ModelState is invalid because the ResourceAssociation is null.

I can't specify the property in WithOne (e.g. `WithOne(x => x.Product)`) because ResourceAssociation is a table that will also be used for other tables (for example Brand also has a ResourceAssociation_Id column pointing to that table).

Is this kind of setup even possible in EF Core? Or will I have to add the different navigation properties to my ResourceAssociation class (ie Product, Brand,...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In EF Core, `HasOne` / `WithOne` (even with navigation properties) are not enough for determining which is the principal and which is the dependent entity in the one-to-one relationship (for one-to-many the one is always principal, many is the dependent, and for many-to-many there is not principal/dependent).

Because of that, the *generic type argument* of `HasForeignKey` / `HasPrincipalKey` is *required* for determination of respectively dependent / principal entity. This is actually explained in the [Other Relationship Patterns - One-to-one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#one-to-one) EF Core documentation topic:

> When configuring the relationship with the Fluent API, you use the `HasOne` and `WithOne` methods.
>
> When configuring the foreign key you need to specify the dependent entity type - notice the generic parameter provided to `HasForeignKey` in the listing below. In a one-to-many relationship it is clear that the entity with the reference navigation is the dependent and the one with the collection is the principal. But this is not so in a one-to-one relationship - hence the need to explicitly define it.

So what you need here is to specify `Product` as being the dependent of the relationship, along with the FK property / column name:

```cs
builder.HasOne(t => t.ResourceAssociation)
    .WithOne() // ok, no navigation
    .HasForeignKey<Product>("ResourceAssociation_Id") // FK name in the dependent
    //               ^^^ the dependent entity of the relationship
    .IsRequired(false)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Comment: Thanks. I also had to make the property nullable (add a question mark behind the type where I declare the property).

Comment: Correction on my previous comment: I had moved my models to a new project where the non-nullable reference types was set to "enable". Removing it (default = disable) makes EF Core behave in the old way, in regards to required/optional properties.

Comment: Yeah, that's part of the NRT support in EF Core.